Laravel Login as User failed & session folder, file permission issue
Currently, I'm working on the Laravel 8 application. In this, we use Login as another user from admin. recently I've been facing an issue, when I logged in as another user while navigating to pages it automatically logged out from the current user back to admin. not able to troubleshoot where it occurs, sometimes in logs, I can see permission denied for creating sessions inside storage/framework/session.
In Controller
public function stopImpersonate(){
    Auth::user()->stopImpersonating();
    return redirect()->route('home');
}

public function loginas($userid){
    $user=User::findOrFail($userid);
    Session::put('impersonate', $user->id);
        return redirect()->route('home')->withStatus(__('LoggedIn as ').$user->name);
}


In Middleware
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)    {
    if (Session::has('impersonate')) {
        $userId = Session::get('impersonate');
        $user = User::find($userId);
        if ($user) {
            Auth::setUser($user);
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}


In Route
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','impersonate']], function () {

});

Any idea on this? could anyone give a suggestion to fix both issues (Loginas & file permission)
I checked Google many of them suggested changing the file permission of the folder to 777. I tried that also. after executing this command from the terminal, log in as working for some time but again the file permission changed to 775. I don't know how it reverts back.
currently, I host my application in web host cpanel. in this, I hosted multiple sites. for the particular application I use the below command to prevent the "access denied" error. but sometimes later it reverts back.
chmod -R 775 /home/site/public_html/storage
chmod -R 777 /home/site/public_html/storage/framework/cache/
chmod -R 777 /home/site/public_html/storage/logs/
chmod -R 777 /home/site/public_html/storage/framework/sessions/
chmod -R 777 /home/site/public_html/storage/framework/views/
chmod -R 777 /home/site/public_html/storage/framework/cache/data/
chmod -R 775 /home/site/public_html/bootstrap/cache

